# Rails 5: prevent deletion in callback

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

Why does this callback in Rails 5 not halt deletion:

```
before_destroy :document_check

def document_check
  if documents.present?
    errors.add(:article, 'in use cannot be deleted')
    throw :abort
  end
end
```

[This post](http://blog.bigbinary.com/2016/02/13/rails-5-does-not-halt-callback-chain-when-false-is-returned.html) explains the differences between Rails 4 and 5, so my callback should prevent deletion if the model has any `documents`, but my record is still being deleted. My deletion test fails with this error:

```
TypeError:
    exception class/object expected
```

How do I return a class or object with a `throw :abort` statement?

Comment: this validation can be done on the relation definition: `has_many :documents, dependent: :restrict`

Comment: It's `:restrict_with_error` for Rails 5, but thank-you! I had no idea that option existed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a simple restrict option that is given when declaring the relation:

```
class SomeModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Rails 4+
  has_many :documents, dependent: :restrict_with_exception
  # Rails 3
  has_many :documents, dependent: :restrict
```

See more in the documentation for all the possible options for `dependent` here: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_many (ctrl+f ":restrict_with_")